# Creating a matrix with given row column,but have a output formatting problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, formatting

I have a question on creating an r*c matrix with given number of rows and columns.
I wrote this which takes r number of rows and c number of columns but the problem is in the output formatting, i require a exact output format and can't seem to get it even after trying for so long, if anyone could help me.

```
def matprint(r, c):
max = r*c
l=[]
for i in range(1,max+1):
    l.append(i)
subList = [l[n:n+c] for n in range(0, len(l),c)]
for q in subList:
    list1 = q
    print( ( '{} ' * len(list1) ).format( *list1 ) )
```

[image]

see the difference is that mine prints "\n" after spaces and also on the last line. it is not a logical problem, just need help with the formatting.
Thank You

Comment: Did you try just `print(*list1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `str.join` to join a list of strings.

This code produces a string of items from `list1`, separeted by `' '`, but also adds a white space at the end:

```
print( ( '{} ' * len(list1) ).format( *list1 ) )
```

Instead of that, do this:

```
list_of_strings = [str(x) for x in list1]
print(' '.join(list_of_strings))
```

Or, more compact:

```
print(' '.join(str(x) for x in list1))
```

You have the same problem with the newlines. `print` adds them after each line. You don't want them after the last line, so you should join the lines as well and then print them without a newline:

```
lines = [' '.join(str(x) for x in list1) for list1 in subList]
sys.stdout.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the problem:

- print a sublist if it is the first one - without newline after it
- if it is not the first one, print a newline followed by the next sublist

that way your last line does not have to `\n` at its end:

```
def matprint(r, c):
    data = list(range(1,r*c+1))               
    l= [data[i*c:i*c+c] for i in range(r)]

    formatter = ('{} ' * c).strip()     # create the format string once - strip spaces at end

    for i,sublist in enumerate(l):
        if i: # 0 is False, all others are True
            print("")
        print( formatter.format( *sublist ), end="" ) # do not print \n at end


matprint(3, 5)
```

I optimized the code a bit as well - you should not use things like `max,min,list,dict,...` as variable names - they hide the build in functions of the same name.

Your list construction can be streamlined by a list comprehension that chunks your numbers list - see [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) .

You do not need to recompute the length of your sublist - it is `c` long.

You need [the index from `enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to decide if the list is "first" - and you need [the `end=""` option of print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to avoid autoprinting newlines.

---

A simpler version without enumerate could be done using list slicing:

```
def matprint(r, c):
    data = list(range(1,r*c+1))
    l= [data[i*c:i*c+c] for i in range(r)]
    formatter = ('{} ' * c).strip()     # create the format string once - strip spaces at end

    print(formatter.format(*l[0]), end="")  # print the 1st element w/o newline
    for sublist in l[1:]: 
        # print all others including a \n in front
        print( "\n"+formatter.format( *sublist ), end="" ) # do not print \n at end
```